Why does pyright strict mode not flag "for k, v in dict" without "items()" as an error?
I have the following code in test.py:
my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 3}
for k, v in my_dict:
   print(k)
   print(v)

When I run pyright pytest.py this is not flagged as an error, even though in my understanding there is enough information to know that my_dict.__iter__ returns Iterable[keys] and the type checker must be able to infer that the tuple unpacking would fail.

It seems that Pyright doesn't have a dedicated option to flag attempts at unpacking strings - it doesn't even flag a, b, c = str(). mypy added a warning for this a while back: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6406

You were on the right track, but stopped short of identifying what keys is. Pyright does indeed have enough information to infer that my_dict.__iter__ returns an Iterable[str], and str values are unpackable. Whether the string has exactly two characters is beyond the scope of PyRight to check, which is why dROOOze mentions to an option to flag attempts at unpacking (i.e., be overly conservative instead of overly liberal).

Pyright assumes that the dictionary keys are strings, which are iterable.
Tuple unpacking is a valid operation on iterables (even though it can still fail if the number of values is wrong).
If you change one of the keys to an integer (which is not iterable), you will get the error you expected.
